# hook_menu() items disappeared and no longer work

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm feel like I'm losing my mind here. I have written a custom module and implemented `hook_menu` to add custom admin pages. Last week this worked perfectly - this week they stopped working then vanished altogether. I can't understand what the problem is and I can't even get simple pages to work now.

This is the code I am using.

#### nhs_session_judge.module

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function nhs_session_judge_menu() {
  $items['admin/session-judging'] = array(
    'title' => 'Your judging',
    'page callback' => 'your_judging_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Custom page callback
 */
function your_judging_page() {
  $content['raw_markup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<p>This table shows at-a-glance the session bids you have already scored and those yet to be judged.</p>',
  );

  // …

  return $content;
}
```

If I use a backup of the database and visit the page, it works.

If I make a change, I get this error.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'your_judging_page' not found or invalid function name in menu_execute_active_handler()

If I clear the cache, the menu item disappears. Visiting the page by entering the URL directly in the browser address bar just redirects to /admin.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I can't make any changes/fixes to this because as soon as I do it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I had a backup of the `nhs_session_judge.module` file in `sites/all/modules/custom/bak/nhs_session_judge.module` and I guess drupal was reading it instead of the `sites/all/modules/custom/nhs_session_judge/nhs_session_judge.module` I was working on, hence why my changes were ignored then lost.